# Cordova iOS plugin not prompting user for location permission

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, cllocationmanager

I'm writing an iOS cordova plugin for my app that is attempting to receive background geolocation updates via iOS' significant change API.  I have the following plugin code:

```
import os.log;
import CoreLocation;

@objc(MyPlugin) class MyPlugin: CDVPlugin, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func pluginInitialize() {
        super.pluginInitialize()
        os_log("[MyPlugin] - plugin initialize")

        locationManager.delegate = self;
    }

    func initBackgroundGeolocation(_ command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
        os_log("[MyPlugin] - initBackgroundGeolocation")

        if (CLLocationManager.significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable()) {
            os_log("[MyPlugin] - significant location change is available")
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization();
        } else {
            os_log("[MyPlugin] - significant location change is not available")
        }

        os_log("[MyPlugin] - location manager is configured")

        let pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_OK)
        self.commandDelegate!.send(pluginResult, callbackId: command.callbackId)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,  didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        os_log("[MyPlugin] - received a location update")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {   
        switch status {
        case .restricted, .denied:
            os_log("[MyPlugin] - denied authorization")
            break

        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            os_log("[MyPlugin] - received when in use authorization")
            break

        case .authorizedAlways:
            os_log("[MyPlugin] - received always usage authorization")
            os_log("[MyPlugin] - starting significant location change monitoring")

            locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges();
            break

        case .notDetermined:
            os_log("[MyPlugin] - status not determined")
            break
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        os_log("[MyPlugin] - did fail with error was called")
    }
}
```

I believe I'm correctly adding the necessary Info.plist entries, via my plugin.xml.  Here's the relevant portion:

```
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string>$ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION</string>
    </config-file>
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription">
        <string>$ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION</string>
    </config-file>
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string>$WHEN_IN_USE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION</string>
    </config-file>

    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="UIBackgroundModes">
        <array>
            <string>location</string>
        </array>
    </config-file>
```

When I call `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization();`, I'm expecting to have iOS prompt the user to grant access to their location.  However, this is not happening.  I stepped through the code in the debugger, and the call appears to be executed successfully, yet nothing happens.

I'm new to iOS, Swift and cordova plugin development, so it's very possible that I'm missing something that's quite obvious.  All suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know I am very late but posting my answer here as it may be helpful to someone. :)

The `requestAlwaysAuthorization` will show prompt only for the first time. From then onwards, no prompts are shown.

It is described in the Apple docs (refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620551-requestalwaysauthorization))

> Core Location limits calls to requestAlwaysAuthorization(). After your app calls this method, further calls have no effect.